# I want to pass three different strings to my main method in java. How do I do this?

Tags: java

I want people to enter there first name then middle name then last name inside of a method. I then want to pass all three variables into my main method.

Is there anyway I can do this?

And how would I get the different data stored in my main method?

Comment: Write a class or struct containing the names

Comment: I slightly modified your question, hope this does fit. What exactly do you mean by 'main method' - I guess it relates to just a method and not **the** main method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't but use `Command line` arguments.

```
public class YourProgram
{
   public static void main(String []args)
    {

    }
}

c:\>java YourProgram "First String" "Second String" "Third String"
```

Answer (score 1):

If by main you refer to application's entry point, the main method.
E.g.

```
public class SomeClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         String firstName = args[0];
         String middleName = args[1];
         String lastName = args[2];
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it as a three arguments after program name when you call it. 
java SomeClass "first name" "middle  name" "last name"

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the actual main method, as in the first method that runs, you can't pass in any variables because there isn't a place to pass a variable, it's where the program starts.

**edit:** as AVD said, you can pass the variables if you run the program from the console, but not inside the code itself.